# Override webpack config on CRA 3.x without ejecting

Tags: reactjs, webpack, create-react-app

I try to customize webpack config on CRA 3.x without ejecting. I want to custom build output on a external directory.
The unique solution i have seen is to use the plugin react app rewired, but it seems to work only on CRA < 2.
Is there another way to achieve this without ejecting my CRA ?

Comment: Are you sure that react-app-rewired doesn't fulfill your needs? [This issue](https://github.com/timarney/react-app-rewired/issues/394) might be useful.

Comment: I didn't see this issue ... only other articles on old versions of cra... i ll retry, thanks

Comment: Hi @Dujard, I see you're new to SO. If you feel an answer solved the problem, please mark it as 'accepted' by clicking the green check mark. This helps keep the focus on older SO which still don't have answers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to [this issue](https://github.com/timarney/react-app-rewired/issues/394#issuecomment-506311912), [react-app-rewired](https://github.com/timarney/react-app-rewired) is now support CRA@3